# Wrong gamma/color lut on mtkview display on iPhone Xs

Tags: ios, swift, metal, color-space

I'm configuring an MTKView with `colorPixelFormat = .rgba16Float`. On the 8+, the display is fine. On the Xs, the display is off by a gamma of 2.2.

If you take a screenshot of the app, the screenshot is the correct color. If you pull the data out of the MTKView and write it into a UIImage, save it, that is correct as well. If you display that UIImage in a UIImageView, the color is correct on the phone.

If I add a gamma 2.2 to the vertex shader, the display is correct (on the Xs, but wrong on the 8+). However, then screenshots and UIImage's saved from the metalview are wrong.

I can't seem to find any display-specific gamma or colorspace settings. Any one else hit this?